# WSO2 DSS: Unable to connect to Google spreradsheet

Tags: wso2, google-sheets, wso2-data-services-server

I am trying to connect to a newly created Google spreadsheet, using the WSO2 Data Services Server (DSS), but it keeps giving me an error when I test the connection. I am using WSO2 DSS 3.2.1 with JDK 1.7.0_60 on Windows.

The sample Google spreadsheet is working fine.

It looks like this problem is due to the new format of the Google Doc URLs (introduced in March 2014)

https://docs.google.com/a/ishafoundation.org/spreadsheets/d/1U0uI5sKHy0WVgQcVtZ4mYMHSzTYZZJse35xy1Y1N7Xg/edit#gid=0

The older format is:

https://docs.google.com/a/ishafoundation.org/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1U0uI5sKHy0WVgQcVtZ4mYMHSzTYZZJse35xy1Y1N7Xg&usp=drive_web#gid=0

As a workaround to this, I am creating my spreadsheet in the old version of Google Sheets, using this link:

https://g.co/oldsheets

However, this message is on the Google Sheets help page

> *Spreadsheets created in the old version of Sheets will eventually be converted to the new Sheets, which won’t require any action on your
>   part. More details coming soon. Thanks

This looks a bit scary to me, since it basically means that my data service will break at some random point in the future when Google decide to change the URL formats... Can someone from WSO2 let me know if this will be fixed in the next DSS update, and when we can expect it to be released.

Just a suggestion - but wouldn't it be better if we only had to enter the unique key for the spreadsheet (instead of the full link), and the DSS server used the Google Sheets API to retrieve the data. This might make our implementations a little more future-proof.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will be fixed in DSS 3.2.2 release. Associated JIRA is [DS-930](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-930).  Alpha pack can be found from [this location](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/scratch/chunk13-release/14-09-2014/wso2dss-3.2.2.zip)

Thanks

Chanika

Comment: just downloaded dss 3.2.2 and problem remains :(

Comment: tried several scenarios, with sharing, private, public, etc. With private I get Invalid User Credentials when testing the connection, otherwise I get Not Found. When running from TryIt, I get a fault with some redirect message.

Comment: Google has changed the authentication mechanism  (OAuth2) recently as you can see from https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2. We will fix this issue in our next release. The JIRA to track this issue is  https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-1049